# Dynamic text format

Tags: javascript, string, format

How should I go about dynamicly insert a `.` on a string in `JavaScript`

e.g:

if the input is `100`, the output should be `1.00`

if the input is `10000`, the output should be `100.00`

if the input is `100000`, the output should be `1000.00`

so on and so on..

I'm trying to use `Intl.NumberFormat` to currency format a string that I fetch from the API. `Intl.NumberFormat` only return corret decimal numbers if the input if the input tells where the `,` should be, but the API only returns raw numbers.

Comment: you can use `toFixed(2)` the value has to be a Number.

Comment: alternatively, the substr function, `x.substr(0, x.length - 2) + "." + x.substr(x.length - 2)` to put a letter 2 away from the end of any string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like `toFixed`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

So:

```
let number = 100;

let float = Number.parseFloat(number/100).toFixed(2);

console.log(float); // Output is 1.00
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!Accepting this as an answer whenever its enabled!

Comment: @ConstantinTrepadus i saw that a second after I posted original, it's been corrected. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toFixed()` to achieve the result.
E.g. `(100).toFixed(2)` will result in `100.00`.

Hence, you can easily do the maths for your requirement.

Comment: but based on the calculation that needs to be done, doesn't it require 100 to be translated to 1.00

Comment: @RohanBhangui It will require some simple mathematics. `(100 / 100).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.splice = function(idx, rem, str) {
    return this.slice(0, idx) + str + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem));
};

var str = "10"; 

if(str.length > 2) {
    str =  str.splice(-2, 0, ".");
}

console.log(str);
```

This will work with strings and the output will be as expected.
100 becomes 1.00 as desired and not 100.00

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid future problems with different formats, either format the numbers as string or use external libraries.
Here is a small "dirty" example :

```
var myNumber= "10";
var dataLenght = myNumber.length;
var result = "";

if (dataLenght > 2) {
    result = myNumber.substring(0, dataLenght - 2) + "." + myNumber.substring(dataLenght - 2, dataLenght);
 } else {
   result = myNumber;
 }
    console.log(result)
```